# Linearising a Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I have the function $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = f(y - x)$, where $y$ and $x$ are functions of $t$. We also have that $f(0) = 0$.

It then says,

> Now, any reasonable function has a tangent line approximation, and since $f(0) = 0$, we have $f(z) \approx kz$. That is, when $|z|$ is fairly small, $f(z)$ is fairly close to $kz$. (From calculus you know that $k = f'(0)$, but we won't use that here).

I understand that we have $f(0) = 0$, but I don't understand the section

> ... we have $f(z) \approx kz$. That is, when $|z|$ is fairly small, $f(z)$ is fairly close to $kz$. (From calculus you know that $k = f'(0)$, but we won't use that here).

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to help me understand this.

Comment: Since $f(0)=0$, we have $f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)}{h}$.  We can rewrite this as $f(h)=f'(0)h+a(h)$, where $a(h)/h\to 0$ as $h\to 0$.  If we replace $h$ with $z$, then this says $f(z)\approx f'(0)z$ when $z$ is small.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Where did you get $a(h)/h$ from? You wrote $f(h)=f'(0)h+a(h)$.

Comment: If we rearrange the limit definition, we have $\lim_{h\to 0}\left[\frac{f(h)}{h}-f'(0)\right]=0$, so let's put $b(h)=\frac{f(h)}{h}-f'(0)$.  Then this limit condition says $b(h)\to 0$ as $h\to 0$.  Rearranging, we have $f(h)=f'(0)h+h b(h)$, so we can put $a(h)=h b(h)$.  Note that $a(h)/h=b(h)\to 0$ as $h\to 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I understand it now.